# Android : Testing viewmodel with coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, coroutine, android-viewmodel

I have this testing method

```
private var testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

 @Test
fun test__success() {
    viewModel = MyActivateViewModel(
            "LG_NAME",
            "EXH_NAME",
            "_CODE",
            "C_CODE", controller)
    every {
        controller.activate(any(), any())  
    } returns true

    testDispatcher
            .runBlockingTest {
                viewModel.onOkButtonClicked()
              Truth.assertThat(viewModel.activated.value).isEqualTo(true)
            }

}


fun onOkButtonClicked() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val status = activateTask()



            if (status == 0) {
                activated.value = true
            } else {
                activationFailed.value = status
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun activateTask(): Int {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var status = 0
            try {
                controller.activate(code, code)
            } catch (e: LoginException) {
                status = e.reason
            }
            status
        }
    }
```

Since I am calling `runBlockingTest {
                viewModel.onOkButtonClicked()`
I expect this to be completed. But the assert below these lines are failing. What i see is the coroutine is not finished before the assert line is executed. If i add a delay before assert, it works as expected.

What is wrong in my implemetation?
what is the right way